# PrimeNg Calendar: Default time for selecting start date with time - should be start of day time that is 00:00:00

Tags: angular, primeng

I am using PrimeNg calendar widget with 2 fields that is startDate and endDate.

Currently when selecting startDate, It is showing the selected date with current time but my requirement is, selected date with start of the day time that is 00:00:00.

and when in endDate field, we are are selecting date it is showing selected date with current time but i want selected date with end of the day time that is 23:59:59.

I am using Angular 7 with primeNg(primefaces).

Please help in to short out the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can use setHours, setMinutes and setSeconds method of date object. PrimeNg p-calendar uses the date object.

Here it is.
component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  date1 = new Date();
  date2 = new Date();
  constructor(){
    this.date1.setHours(0);
    this.date1.setMinutes(0);
    this.date1.setSeconds(0);
    this.date2.setHours(0);
    this.date2.setMinutes(0);
    this.date2.setSeconds(0);
  }
}
```

Component.html

```
<div class="ui-g-12 ui-md-4">
        <h3>Start Time</h3>
        <p-calendar [(ngModel)]="date1" [showTime]="true" hourFormat="24"></p-calendar>
    </div>
<br>

<div class="ui-g-12 ui-md-4">
        <h3>End Time</h3>
        <p-calendar [(ngModel)]="date2" [showTime]="true" hourFormat="24"></p-calendar>
</div>
```

[working code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-primeng-dropdowns-bug-jcgufn)

Comment: Using this code i am not able to change the time from calendar. It is only setting the value of the time but when trying to change the time it is not changing the time in calendar.

Comment: I have gone through the different blogs and find out this link where at the end of the discussion they have marked as fixed.

**Still not sure what exactly is the fix**

https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/issues/4486#issuecomment-346957996

Check the 3rd point. Not sure, what is the fix.

Comment: I am not sure, there were issues with primeNG calendar in early versions. For your problem, I think it can be done, Maybe I got something else. If you could explain a bit with stackblitz that would be helpful.

Comment: Started working after updating the calendar library with the new one. It is a problem with the old library and it has been fixed with the new one.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of handling a prime range picker calendar with moment.

```
onRangeDateFilterApply(): void {
        if (this.rangeDateFilterValue[0] && this.rangeDateFilterValue[1]) {

            const timezoneOffset = moment(this.rangeDateFilterValue[0]).utcOffset();

            this.dateFilter = {
                dateRange: { from: moment(this.rangeDateFilterValue[0]).utc().add(timezoneOffset, 'minutes').startOf('day').format(), to: moment(this.rangeDateFilterValue[1]).utc().add(timezoneOffset, 'minutes').endOf('day').format()}
            }
            // do stuff
        }
}
```